# Xcode 8.0 CBCentralManager Issue

Tags: swift, xcode, core-bluetooth, ios10, xcode8

I recently downloaded Xcode 8.0 and trying to run my previous project which uses core bluetooth.

I have enabled **Use Legacy Swift Language Version** in build setting for compatibility in swift 2.3
everything works, but one Issue occured,

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager)
{
    print("state is \(central.state.rawValue)")
    if (central.state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn)
    {
        self.centralManager?.scanForPeripheralsWithServices([serviceUUID], options: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        // do something like alert the user that ble is not on
    }
}
```

previously **central.state** would return **CBCentralManagerState** type as int but now it returns **CBManagerState** so got an error so i changed to

```
 if (central.state == CBManagerState.PoweredOn)
```

But **CBManagerState** is only supported in IOS 10+ but i want to build it for IOS 8.3+ so how can I change the code?

**UPDATE**
I also converted project to swift 3.0, but still same issue, so how can i run this project on mobiles with ios version below 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach is just to use the short-hand reference to the enumeration value:

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager)
{
    print("state is \(central.state.rawValue)")
    if (central.state == .PoweredOn)
    {
        self.centralManager?.scanForPeripheralsWithServices([serviceUUID], options: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        // do something like alert the user that ble is not on
    }

}
```

Now your code will compile without errors or warnings and works correctly on all targets